# How can I add months Int to a choosen date on date picker in android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a working date picker in my app that replaces an `EditText` after a date selection. I want to add duration through a `RadioGroup` button that prints an Int to provoke an end date. How can I do that? I've spent the last two days without getting the result I'm looking to get.

Here is what I've got so far.

```kotlin
    val datePicker = findViewById<DatePicker>(R.id.date_Picker)
            val today = Calendar.getInstance()
            datePicker.init(
                today.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                today.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH
            ) { view, year, month, day ->
                val month = month + 1
    
                val startDay = ("$day-$month-$year")
    
                binding.fechadeinicio.text = fechainicio

                val duration = when (binding.duracion.checkedRadioButtonId) {
                            R.id.doce -> 12
                            R.id.veinticuatro -> 24
                            R.id.treintayseis -> 36
                            else -> 36
                        }
    
                  //  val endDate = startDate.plusMonths(Duration.toLong())
                 //   binding.endDate.text = endDate.toString()
               }
```

Here is the closest one to the result I'm looking to get. Yet, I want to use the selected date val startDay, instead of `val date = LocalDate.parse("2020-05-03")`. When I replace it, the app crashes.

```kotlin
    val date = LocalDate.parse("2020-05-03")
    // Displaying date
    println("Date : $date")
    // Add 2 months to the date
    val newDate = date.plusMonths(2)
    println("New Date : $newDate")
```

Please, let me know how I can get the desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: `format the val date with the c, the app crashes.` What is `c` here?

Comment: My bad, there was a typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use the selected date that is `val startDay` instead of `val date = LocalDate.parse("2020-05-03")`. When I replace it, the app crashes.

`val startDay = ("$day-$month-$year")` here you've created date as `dd-MM-yyyy`, but by default `LocalDate.parse` uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` to parse a string, that parses a string of format `yyyy-MM-dd` to `LocalDate`. That's why it's crashing as your date is invalid according to that format.

You have to provide a `DateTimeFormatter` of pattern `dd-MM-yyyy` to parse your date.

You can do it like this

```
val startDay = ("$day-$month-$year")
val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
binding.fechadeinicio.text = fechainicio

val duration = when (binding.duracion.checkedRadioButtonId) {
    R.id.doce -> 12
    R.id.veinticuatro -> 24
    R.id.treintayseis -> 36
    else -> 36
}

val startDate = LocalDate.parse(startDay, dateFormatter)
val endDate = startDate.plusMonths(duration.toLong()).format(dateFormatter)
binding.endDate.text = endDate
```

---

`DatePicker` returns year, month and day `int` values, now on creating date like `val startDay = ("$day-$month-$year")` would result in single digit for days and months less than 10, which would return `1 Jan 2020` as `1-1-2020` but date formatter is expecting it to be `01-01-2020`.

To deal with this, we've to format `int` values before assigning it to the `startDay`, we can use `format` method of `String` to return 2 digits like this `"%02d".format(intValue)`

Change

```
val startDay = ("$day-$month-$year")
```

to

```
val startDay = "${"%02d".format(day)}-${"%02d".format(month)}-$year"
```

Comment: Check what exception you are getting in logcat.

Comment: Thank you soooo much for your help, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalDate` using `of` function.

Example here:

```
    val date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day)
    // Displaying date
    println("Date : $date")
    // Add 2 months to the date
    val newDate = date.plusMonths(2)
    println("New Date : $newDate")
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I get the error message "None of the following functions can be called with the argument supplied.